# How to create new Tags from results containing delimiter " USE "?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

**Updated Question**

So I am running a query and some of the results have the structure `"keyword USE 1 or more keywords"`. When a user selects entries like this, I want the input field to show the keyword(s) to the right of USE. I got it to work for the first select thanks to @DavidDomain, but now I have a new Problem. The selects goes wild after the first selection. I tried to create a Jsfiddler, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I copied code directly from my IDE. Here is the original [project](http://auburn.edu/~blj0011/PlainsmanIndex2/). If you type in USE and select one of the options, it works perfectly. If you try another selection then it goes crazy. Here is the JSFiddle I tried to create that shows what I did to get to this point.

```js
$('.productName').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/9t7gz",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        key: params.term // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
        if (data[d].text.includes(" USE ")) {
          var dataItems = data[d].text.split(" USE ");
          if (dataItems[1].toString().includes(";")) {
            var dataKeywordItems = dataItems[1].toString().split(";");
            for (var ii = 0; ii < dataKeywordItems.length; ii++) {
              var option3 = new Option(dataKeywordItems[ii].toString().trim(), dataKeywordItems[ii].toString().trim(), true);
              $('.productName').append(option3);
            }
          } else {
            var option = new Option(dataItems[1], dataItems[1], true);
            $('.productName').append(option);
          }
        }
      }
      return {
        results: data
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  placeholder: 'Keyword/keyphrase search...',
  minimumInputLength: 2,
  tags: true
}).on("select2:select", function(e) {
  var splitValues = $('.productName').val().toString().split(" USE ");

  if (splitValues[1].includes("; ")) {
    var splitKeywords = splitValues[1].toString().split("; ");

    $('.productName').val(splitKeywords).trigger("change");
    alert(splitKeywords.toString());
    //                for(var i = 0; i < splitKeywords.length; i++)
    //                {
    //                    alert(splitKeywords[i].toString().trim());
    //                    $('.productName').val(splitKeywords[i].toString().trim()).trigger("change");
    //                }
  } else {
    $('.productName').val(splitValues[1]).trigger("change");
  }

});
```

```css
.select2-selection__rendered {
  line-height: 32px !important;
}

.select2-selection {
  height: 34px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class='input-group-btn col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
        <select style="width:70%;" class='productName ' id='productName' width=>

        </select>
        
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The two important parts of my code are below:

> ProcessResults:

If a keyword contains " USE " this takes the one or more keywords to the right of " USE " and dynamically adds them to the dropdown list.

```
processResults: function (data) {                      
    for(var d = 0; d < data.length; d++)
    {
        if(data[d].text.includes(" USE "))
        {
            var dataItems = data[d].text.split(" USE ");
            if(dataItems[1].toString().includes(";"))
            {
                var dataKeywordItems = dataItems[1].toString().split(";");
                for(var ii = 0; ii < dataKeywordItems.length; ii++)
                {                                    
                    var option3 = new Option(dataKeywordItems[ii].toString().trim(), dataKeywordItems[ii].toString().trim(), true);
                    $('.productName').append(option3);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var option = new Option(dataItems[1], dataItems[1], true);
                $('.productName').append(option);
            }                            
        }
    }
    return {
        results: data
    };
},
```

> On select:

This takes a selected keyword that contains " USE " and extracts the 1 or more keywords to the right of " USE " and diplays them in the input field.

```
.on("select2:select", function(e) {            
    var splitValues = $('.productName').val().toString().split(" USE ");  

    if(splitValues[1].includes("; "))
    {                 
        var splitKeywords = splitValues[1].toString().split("; ");

        $('.productName').val(splitKeywords).trigger("change");
        alert(splitKeywords.toString());
//                for(var i = 0; i < splitKeywords.length; i++)
//                {
//                    alert(splitKeywords[i].toString().trim());
//                    $('.productName').val(splitKeywords[i].toString().trim()).trigger("change");
//                }
    }
    else
    {
        $('.productName').val(splitValues[1]).trigger("change");
    }

});
```

A screenshot of the first select:
[image: Screenshot of first select]

A screenshot of a potential second select:
[image]

The question is how can I keep the first select results and add the new second select results?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for that to show what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Let me try to create something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get the crappy JsFiddles to work, so I am going to post my answer from my original problem. The process is the same. After a lot of searching and mixing different answers together, I came up with this solution.

```
    $('.productName').select2({            
        ajax: {
            url: "DBHandler.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {   
                return {
                    key: params.term // search term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {                       
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },                
            cache: true
        },
        placeholder: 'Keyword/keyphrase search...',
        minimumInputLength: 2,   
        tags: true
    }).on("select2:select", function(e) {  
        var valueToRemove = e.params.data.id; 
        if(valueToRemove.toString().includes(" USE "))
        {
            var splitValues = valueToRemove.toString().split(" USE "); 
            if(!splitValues[1].toString().includes(";"))
            {                  
                alert("value does not contain ;");
                new_data = $.grep($('.productName').val(), function(id){return id !== valueToRemove;});
                alert("new data: " + new_data);

                $('.productName > option').prop("selected", false);
                $('.productName').val(new_data).trigger('change');  

                $('.productName').append("<option value = '" + splitValues[1].toString().trim() + "' selected>" + splitValues[1].toString().trim() + "</option>");              
            }
            else
            {
                var splitKeys = splitValues[1].toLocaleString().split(";");
                new_data = $.grep($('.productName').val(), function(id){return id !== valueToRemove;});
                $('.productName > option').prop("selected", false);
                $('.productName').val(new_data).trigger('change');  

                splitKeys.forEach(function(item)
                {
                    alert(item);
                    $('.productName').append("<option value = '" + item.toString().trim() + "' selected>" + item.toString().trim() + "</option>");
                });                    
            }
        }           
    });
```

The onSelect code is the key to solving this problem.

```
on("select2:select", function(e) {...});
```

I started by getting the value that is being selected. If this value contains `" USE "`, I do not want it to be included in the `InputField` values.

```
var valueToRemove = e.params.data.id;
```

I then split this value using `" USE "` as the delimiter. If the keyword(s) to the right of `" USE "` do not contain a semi-colon `;`, I create an array `new_data` that holds all of the `InputField`'s current values except the value that is being selected. I then, deselect all of the current selected values using `$('.productName > option').prop("selected", false);`. Next, I added all of the old selected values back using `$('.productName').val(new_data).trigger('change');`. Finally, I append the new keyword that was extracted from the original selected value using `$('.productName').append("<option value = '" + splitValues[1].toString().trim() + "' selected>" + splitValues[1].toString().trim() + "</option>");`. This handles the case of having only one keyword after `" USE "`. **Example keyword:** `Not smart USE dumb`. When this is select only `dumb` shows up as a keyword in the `InputField`.

```
        if(valueToRemove.toString().includes(" USE "))
        {
            var splitValues = valueToRemove.toString().split(" USE "); 
            if(!splitValues[1].toString().includes(";"))
            {                  
                alert("value does not contain ;");
                new_data = $.grep($('.productName').val(), function(id){return id !== valueToRemove;});
                alert("new data: " + new_data);

                $('.productName > option').prop("selected", false);
                $('.productName').val(new_data).trigger('change');  

                $('.productName').append("<option value = '" + splitValues[1].toString().trim() + "' selected>" + splitValues[1].toString().trim() + "</option>");              
            }
            else{
                .
                .
                .
            }
        }
```

In the case where the keyword(s) to the right of `" USE "` contains a semi-colon `;`, I first split the string to the right of `" USE "` on the semi-colon `;` using `var splitKeys = splitValues[1].toLocaleString().split(";");`. This gives me all of the keywords that should be added to the `InputField`. Next, I take the exact same step to repopulate the `InputField`'s values.

1. `new_data = $.grep($('.productName').val(), function(id){return id !== valueToRemove;});`
2. `$('.productName > option').prop("selected", false);`
3. `$('.productName').val(new_data).trigger('change');`

I then use a loop to add all of the new keywords that should be added to the input field using:

`splitKeys.forEach(function(item)
 {
     alert(item);
     $('.productName').append("<option value = '" + item.toString().trim() + "' selected>" + item.toString().trim() + "</option>");
 });`

This handles the case of having more than one keyword after " USE ". Example keyword: `Not smart USE dumb; stupid`. When this is select `dumb` and `stupid` show up as keywords in the InputField.

```
    if(valueToRemove.toString().includes(" USE "))
        {
            var splitValues = valueToRemove.toString().split(" USE "); 
            if(!splitValues[1].toString().includes(";"))
            {                  
                .
                .
                .           
            }
            else{
                var splitKeys = splitValues[1].toLocaleString().split(";");
                new_data = $.grep($('.productName').val(), function(id){return id !== valueToRemove;});
                $('.productName > option').prop("selected", false);
                $('.productName').val(new_data).trigger('change');  

                splitKeys.forEach(function(item)
                {
                    alert(item);
                    $('.productName').append("<option value = '" + item.toString().trim() + "' selected>" + item.toString().trim() + "</option>");
                });                    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `formatSelection` method to change how the selected option should be displayed.

Here is an example:

```js
function format(state) {
  if (state.text.indexOf('USE') !== -1) {
    return state.text.substring(state.text.indexOf('USE') + 4, state.text.length);
  }
  return state.text;
}

$('#test').select2({
  data:[
    {id:0,text:"enhancement"},
    {id:1,text:"bug"},
    {id:2,text:"duplicate USE copy"},
    {id:3,text:"invalid USE wrong; incorrect"},
    {id:4,text:"wontfix"}
  ],
  multiple: true,
  width: "300px",
  formatSelection: format,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="test" />
```

Comment: This satisfies one of the conditions. I am working to solve the second condition. If I solve it, I will update and accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what is the second condition ?

Comment: Your answer works great for Condition 1: `{id:2,text:"duplicate USE copy"},`. Condition 2: `{id:3,text:"invalid USE wrong; incorrect"},`. In the second condition, There should be two separate keywords in the input box,  keyword: wrong and keyword: incorrect. With your current answer both keywords appear as one.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I will post and update tomorrow. I had to leave work abruptly to pick my little one up from summer camp. I didn't notice the time.